# How can I write a binary array as an image in Python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have an array of binary numbers in Python:

```
data = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1...]
```

I would like to take this data out and save it as a bitmap, with a '0' corresponding to white and a '1' corresponding to black. I know that there are 2500 numbers in the array, corresponding to a 50x50 bitmap. I've downloaded and installed PIL, but I'm not sure how to use it for this purpose. How can I convert this array into the corresponding image?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24269756/turning-binary-string-into-an-image-with-pil)

Comment: Precisely what does "save it as a bitmap" mean to you? Do you mean that you want to display the image? That you want to save it in GIF or JPG form? That you want to simply write the bits to a file with no image metadata at all?

Comment: You could save it as a netbpm pretty easily, if that's also acceptable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format#PGM_example

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I use the python imaging library to create a bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20304438/how-can-i-use-the-python-imaging-library-to-create-a-bitmap)

Comment: @ap - The duplicate question was limiting the scope of the answer to the Python Imaging Library, when there are other ways to answer the question.

Comment: @Back2Basics asker specifically requests PIL responses, and has tagged his question with python-imaging-library

Comment: ...and yet the asker picked the matplotlib answer.  "...People don't know what they want till you show it to them." - Steve Jobs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `numpy` and `matplotlib` way of doing it would be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np
plt.imsave('filename.png', np.array(data).reshape(50,50), cmap=cm.gray)
```

See [this](http://matplotlib.org/api/image_api.html#matplotlib.image.imsave)

Comment: This works well for me! Only problem is the output is red and blue, not black and white. Any thoughts?

Comment: By default it saves array in jet colormap, black and white would be gray colormap. Will update the answer when i get back to my machine

Answer (score 21):

You can use `Image.new` with [`1`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) mode and put each integer as pixel in your initial image:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> import random

>>> data = [random.choice((0, 1)) for _ in range(2500)]
>>> data[:] = [data[i:i + 50] for i in range(0, 2500, 50)]
>>> print data
[[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, ...], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, ...], [1, 1, 0, 1, ...], ...]

>>> img = Image.new('1', (50, 50))
>>> pixels = img.load()

>>> for i in range(img.size[0]):
...    for j in range(img.size[1]):
...        pixels[i, j] = data[i][j]

>>> img.show()
>>> img.save('/tmp/image.bmp')
```

[image]

Comment: Upvoting since this is the only answer not to use external libraries not mentioned in the original question or tags.

Comment: I get `SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple` on this line: `pixels[i, j] = data[i][j]`. it seems the assigned value must be a tuple so this fixes: `pixels[i, j] = data[i][j], `

Answer (score 4):

**Not for binary array**

In case you have **binary data** in this format - `b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00...`, then you may use this method to write it as an image file:

```
with open("image_name.png", "wb") as img:
    img.write(binary_data)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import scipy.misc
import numpy as np
data = [1,0,1,0,1,0...]
data = np.array(data).reshape(50,50)
scipy.misc.imsave('outfile.bmp', data)
```