# How do I display an image from an array in python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use PIL to display an image from an array. The array is a long list of elements which are pixel values of an image. How do I display these pixel values as an image ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what kind of data is in your list, so I assume it is an array with 25 elements (grouped in 5 groups of 5), which will be converted to a 5 by 5 black & white image.

```
from PIL import Image
import random

data = [
    [1,0,0,1,0],
    [1,1,1,0,0],
    [1,1,0,1,0],
    [1,0,1,1,0],
    [0,1,1,0,1],
    ]
img = Image.new("1", (5, 5))
pixels = img.load()
for i in range(img.size[0]):
    for j in range(img.size[1]):
        pixels[i, j] = data[i][j]

img.show()
img.save("img.png")
```

This is similar to this question: [How can I write a binary array as an image in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32105954/how-can-i-write-a-binary-array-as-an-image-in-python)